# Print ArrayList like Excel spreadsheet

Tags: java

Is there a way to print an ArrayList like a Excel spreadsheet ?

[image: example]
My code is this:

```
private static void printList() {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrizCuadrada.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print(fillWithSpaces(matrizCuadrada.get(i).getValor()));;
    }
}

private static String fillWithSpaces(String cadena) {
    int cantidadEspacios = 9 - cadena.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < cantidadEspacios; i++) {
        cadena += " ";
    }
    return cadena;
}
```

Comment: Say a little more about what you need.

Comment: Just print in console like a Excel spreadsheet format, with columns and rows

Answer (score 0):

To print a one-dimensional data structure like `ArrayList` in two dimensions you are going to have to set a fixed line size. This is actually a very similar problem as loading pixels stored in linearly stacked memory to a two-dimensional image. Check the linked article for more details about this problem.

You need nested loops to achieve this behaviour, which you already have (`fillWithSpaces()` (containing a loop) is called from inside another loop). So, change `fillWithSpaces()` to something like this:

```
private static String fillWithSpaces(String cadena) {
    String line = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i++) {
        line += cadena.charAt(i);
        line += " ";
    }
    return line;
}
```

This code can also be simplified using a utility called `StringJoiner` to join strings and characters with a delimiter:

```
private static String fillWithSpaces(String cadena) {
    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i++) {
        joiner.add(cadena.charAt(i));
    }
    return joiner.toString();
}
```

Also, you need to jump to a new line at the end of the outer loop. This can be done by changing `System.out.print()` to `System.out.println()`, which will automatically output a new line.

Check this article by Daniel Shiffman for an extensive explanation of the same problem in a different context (under **Pixels, pixels, and more pixels**): https://processing.org/tutorials/pixels/